# If $\exp(X) \in G$, and $X$ is Hermitian, do we have $X \in \mathfrak g$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be the $\mathbb R$-points of an algebraic group in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ which is defined over $\mathbb R$.  Let $\mathfrak g$ be the Lie algebra of $G$.  Assume $G$ is topologically connected, and closed under the conjugate transpose $ g \mapsto g^{\ast} = \space ^t\overline{g}$.  Let $$\mathfrak h = \{ X \in \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb C) : \space ^t\overline{X} = X\}$$
be the space of Hermitian matrices, and let $U(n) = \{g \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C) : gg^{\ast} = 1 \}$ be the unitary group.  Let $K = G \cap U(n)$.  By the polar decomposition theorem, we have that 
$$U(n) \times \mathfrak h \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$$ $$(u,X) \mapsto u \exp(X) $$
is a homeomorphism.  If we set $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak h \cap \mathfrak g$, I want to prove the *Cartan decomposition* for $G$, which states that polar decomposition restricts to a homeomorphism

$$K \times \mathfrak p \rightarrow G$$

For $g \in G$, uniquely write $g = k \exp(X)$ for $k \in U(n)$ and $X$ Hermitian.  I know how to show that $k$ actually lies in $K$, and therefore that $\exp(X)$ lies in $G$.  However, I don't see why this implies $X \in \mathfrak p$.

I think my difficulty comes down to the following question: if $X$ is Hermitian, and $\exp(X)$ is in $G$, do we have $X \in \mathfrak g$?

Comment: Take $G = I$, the trivial group. Take $X$ to be the diagonal matrix with all entries $2\pi i$. Then $\exp(X) = 1$. What you need to assume is that $\exp(tX) \in G$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$, or at least $t$ near zero.

Comment: Maybe there is some pathology with zero dimensional things.  Do you think similar counterexamples arise for nontrivial $G$?

Comment: The same example works! Take $G$ to be any subgroup that does not include the diagonal $U(1)$, for instance $SU(n)$.

Comment: The suggested counterexample is not Hermitian. One shows that $\text{exp}(tX) \in G$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ using that $G$ is algebraic and that $\text{exp}(nX) \in G$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This implies $X \in \mathfrak{g}$.